# How to append measurement units in Select Statement in SQL Query within the output

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I'm using Oracle's SQL Developer.

For example, I've table City with two columns - place and speed_limit. Column speed_limit has datatype number(3) and I want query with select statement with return column speed_limit with units (mph) in the output in column speed_limit.

What I should add to the query?

```
SELECT speed_limit
FROM city;
```

to have output like this:

```
speed_limit 
-----------
    20 mph
    40 mph
   100 mph
```

instead of:

```
speed_limit 
-----------
    20
    40
   100
```

Comment: Don't.  This involves turning numeric data into strings, which obfuscates it's natural meaning *(hard to manipulate after you've done it)* and is obviously purely for display purposes.  Presentation transformations should happen in the application / reporting environment and not in the database.  Presentation Layer != Database Layer.

Comment: I was searching this only for my homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(speed_limit) || ' mph'
FROM city
```

Comment: are you not getting output ?

Comment: The `to_char()` is unnecessary.  The concatenation operator handles numbers as well as strings.

Comment: In sql server,this would have given error conversion failed...thnks for pointing out